# Linux CFS scheduling of cron-job vs console

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, cron, cfs

I've created some job (weather forecasting) and it is a heavy load, mostly CPU and memory, for a long(er) time. I notice that when I'm running the job from the cli I can still use my browser without stuttering. But when I move the same job to a cron job there are stutters all over the place.

I think this has to do with the way that CFS scheduling from the kernel will group processes (by tty). See e.g. [here for documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.html).

Now that link does provide some pointers on how to fix it, possibly. But I was wondering if anyone has already done such a thing and what the results were.

`Linux xyz 4.4.0-170-generic #199-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:45:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`